# can we access a server using python script (entering login credentials) without PuTTy

Tags: python-2.7, putty

Can we access a shared network server, using python script entering the necessary credentials like HostName and Password.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the [paramiko](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell) library.

Comment: @merlin2011 could you pl let me know how to install paramiko library. I have downloaded files required but could not get through. Can u suggest me clear way to do it